# D3.js canvas incorrect display in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, svg, d3.js, mozilla

I have a created a d3 canvas like below.

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", 500)
            .attr("height", 1000)
            .append("g").attr("transform", "translate(150,150)");
```

and further added elements to it to create a plot.

I am facing an issue while rendering the it in Google Chrome browser.The graph is displayed towards the left than expected and hence is cut by the panel border.

The same code  is rendered correctly in Mozilla Firefox.
Is there a difference in the way the canvas coordinates are calculated in both the browser? Or is it that transform and translate is misbehaving in chrome?

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how the SVG is displayed differently?  Chrome and Firefox differ in the default size of `<svg>` elements, but that shouldn't make a difference if you are setting height and width attributes.  P.S. When you edit the question, please change the title to use SVG instead of "canvas", which might be mistaken for the `<canvas>` element.  Also "Thanks in advance" and signing the post are discouraged and will be edited out; you can change your user name on [your profile page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2753788/user2753788).

Comment: There's not enough information in the question to answer this. Please add an example that shows the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/3ko8urdv/ looks the same to me in Chrome 39 and Firefox 34 nightly.